# C# - Linq - Techniques for avoiding repeating same pieces of code

Tags: c#, linq

I am writing a piece of code for C# Web Api, letting the clients to pass a column name and sort direction as parameter.
Although there are, like, 30-ish properties, so the following code (despite it works) gets ugly after a while.

What are my options to avoid repeating this seemingly same pieces of code?

````
if (column == nameof(MyModel.ColumnA).ToLower())
{
    if (parameters.IsOrderByAsc)
    {
        return queryResult.OrderBy(q => q.ColumnA);
    }

    return queryResult.OrderByDescending(q => q.ColumnA);
}

if (column == nameof(MyModel.ColumnB).ToLower())
{
    if (parameters.IsOrderByAsc)
    {
        return queryResult.OrderBy(q => q.ColumnB);
    }

    return queryResult.OrderByDescending(q => q.ColumnB);
}

if (column == nameof(MyModel.ColumnC).ToLower())
{
    if (parameters.IsOrderByAsc)
    {
         return queryResult.OrderBy(q => q.ColumnC);
    }

    return queryResult.OrderByDescending(q => q.ColumnC);
}

....


```
````

Comment: Please write an appropriate tile: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: A single switch-statement to replace each outer-if-statement and a function to do the inner-if-statement and returns should make this pretty short and simple. You could also create a dictionary where the key is the column name and the value is the expression (e.g. `q => q.ColumnA`). Then just look up the expression and plug it into the return value.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/233505/648075 ?

Comment: You probably want to use `ToLowerInvariant()`, otherwise the code will behave weirdly in certain locales (e.g. in Turkey `I` does not lowercase to `i`)

Comment: What is `queryResult`? An `IQueryable`, making the orderby go to the translated SQL? Maybe you can add a tag for the specific LINQ flavor you're using (like Entity Framework).

Comment: @CodesInChaos The ordering is probably done by a database, so the collation will be all that matters.

Comment: @GertArnold I'm not talking about the ordering, I'm taking about the mapping from property names to properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to pull in DynamicLinq its not a lot of Expression tree work to get exactly what OP is looking for.  In the constructor getting the methods we need to call for the Queryable, I'm assuming this is IQueryable and not IEnumerable.  If IEnumerable just swap all the Queryable for Enumerable.  For the ToLower matching of the property using the BindingFlag.IgnoreCase.  Also threw in ThenBy as a bonus as wasn't a lot of work.

```
public static class QueryableExtensions
{
    private static readonly MethodInfo _orderBy;
    private static readonly MethodInfo _orderByDescending;
    private static readonly MethodInfo _thenBy;
    private static readonly MethodInfo _thenByDescending;

    static QueryableExtensions()
    {
        Func<IQueryable<object>, Expression<Func<object, object>>, IOrderedQueryable<object>> orderBy = Queryable.OrderBy;
        _orderBy = orderBy.Method.GetGenericMethodDefinition();
        orderBy = Queryable.OrderByDescending;
        _orderByDescending = orderBy.Method.GetGenericMethodDefinition();
        Func<IOrderedQueryable<object>, Expression<Func<object, object>>, IOrderedQueryable<object>> thenBy = Queryable.ThenBy;
        _thenBy = thenBy.Method.GetGenericMethodDefinition();
        thenBy = Queryable.ThenByDescending;
        _thenByDescending = thenBy.Method.GetGenericMethodDefinition();
    }

    public static IOrderedQueryable<TSource> OrderBy<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, string propertyName, bool orderByAscending = true)
    {
        return CreateExpression(source, propertyName, orderByAscending ? _orderBy : _orderByDescending);
    }

    public static IOrderedQueryable<TSource> ThenBy<TSource>(this IOrderedQueryable<TSource> source, string propertyName, bool orderByAscending = true)
    {
        return CreateExpression(source, propertyName, orderByAscending ? _thenBy : _thenByDescending);
    }
    
    private static IOrderedQueryable<TSource> CreateExpression<TSource>(IQueryable<TSource> source, string propertyName, MethodInfo method)
    {
        var propInfo = typeof(TSource).GetProperty(propertyName, BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance) ?? throw new ArgumentException(nameof(propertyName));
        var methodInfo = method.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(TSource), propInfo.PropertyType);
        var sourceParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSource), "source");
        var property = Expression.Property(sourceParam, propInfo);
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda(typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(TSource), propInfo.PropertyType), property, sourceParam);
        var call = Expression.Call(methodInfo, source.Expression, lambda);
        return (IOrderedQueryable<TSource>)source.Provider.CreateQuery<TSource>(call);
    }
}
```

Now can just call it like `return queryResult.OrderBy(column, parameters.IsOrderByAsc)`

This doesn't do nested properties but wouldn't be much work to make that w

Answer (score 4):

If you're willing to use the [DynamicLinq](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=dynamiclinq) library, the problem becomes trivial. It allows you to pass a string parameter to the `OrderBy` method, bypassing your entire logic:

```
queryResult.OrderBy(column)
```

If this is related to doing a SQL database lookup, if you think about it, the issue you're facing it a bit of a self-imposed issue, because you start from a string value and you're eventually going to generate a string value (in the SQL query). The issue you're facing is that standard LINQ forces you to map it to an actual property of the entity, which in this case is an unnecessary mapping which DynamicLinq allows you to bypass.

If you want, you could add a bit of validation to confirm that the passed string is a known property of your entity type.

```
bool columnIsProperty = typeof(MyModel)
                           .GetProperties()
                           .Any(prop => prop.Name.ToLower() == column.ToLower());

if(columnIsProperty)
    queryResult = queryResult.OrderBy(column);
```

Comment: Change `typeof(MyModel).GetType().GetProperties()` to `typeof(MyModel).GetProperties()`. Also it can be cached to some field because Reflection operations aren't enough fast at all.

Comment: @aepot Good catch, I had adapted a different piece of code and forgot to omit the `GetType()`. Caching might be relevant for frequent operations on e.g. an always-on service, but in scope of e.g. a web service where you reflect once for a web request, caching means retaining state, which brings more problems than it solves. I'd be more inclined to generate a list of properties on build instead of caching it at runtime.

Comment: web service can receive many rps (100? 1000? 10k?), btw if you you're fine with Reflection performance, allocating an array of strings is resulting in a GC job. `private static readonly string[] modelPropertyNames = typeof(MyModel).GetProperties().Select(prop => prop.Name.ToLower()).ToArray()` and then `bool columnIsProperty = modelPropertyNames.Any(name => name == column.ToLower())`. That is what means caching for me: storing few data that never changes in memory once and reuse then. Anyway it affects the performance, even for 1rps.