# Database dynamic query

Tags: c#, performance, database, entity-framework-core

I am working with `C#`, `Npgsql`, `EF Core` and `Postgres`.
I defined an endpoint for a paginated search, where the filters and orderBy column are dynamic. The endpoint accepts a `PaginationOptions` instance:

```
public class PaginationOptions
{
    public int Page { get; set; }
    public int ItemsPerPage { get; set; }
    public string OrderBy { get; set; }
    public bool Desc { get; set; }
    public IList<FilterValues> Filters { get; set; }
}

public class FilterValues
{
    public string FieldName { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> Values { get; set; }
}
```

The following method performs the search and returns a Tuple with the sorted items and a counter for the total items in the table:

```
public Tuple<IList<T>, int> Search(PaginationOptions paginationOptions)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(paginationOptions.OrderBy))
    {
        CheckFilterField(paginationOptions.OrderBy);
    }

    int offset = (paginationOptions.Page - 1) * paginationOptions.ItemsPerPage;
    string orderBy = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(paginationOptions.OrderBy) ? paginationOptions.OrderBy : $"{prefix}.title";
    string order = paginationOptions.Desc ? "DESC" : "ASC";

    using (NpgsqlConnection connection = GetConnection())
    {
        string query = $"{GetQueryfields()} {GetFromClause()} {BuildWhere(paginationOptions.Filters)}";
        string itemsQuery = $"SELECT {query} ORDER BY {orderBy} {order}";

        NpgsqlCommand command = BuildCommand(connection, itemsQuery, paginationOptions.Filters);

        IDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        ISet<Guid> guids = new HashSet<Guid>(paginationOptions.ItemsPerPage);
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Guid guid = reader.GetGuid(0);
            if (!guids.Contains(guid))
            {
                guids.Add(guid);
            }
        }
        ISet<Guid> filteredGuids = guids.Skip(offset).Take(paginationOptions.ItemsPerPage).ToHashSet();

        IList<T> items = GetItems(filteredGuids);

        return Tuple.Create(items, guids.Count);
    }
}
```

In words: In each entity there are the query fields and the FROM clause defiend. They are splitted because I need the FROM clause in another method as well.
 The WHERE (prepared statement) and ORDER BY are built dynamically using the parameters. The `BuildCommand` creates the `NpgsqlCommand` and sets the parameters. Then I use Dapper for a raw query in order to get the ids of the requested items, then I load them using the `EF` and at the end I `Skip` and `Take` in order to have the right pagination.
The problem ist that `EF` does not allow to add an ORDER BY clause for raw queries, it is only available throug the `Linq` expression:

```
context.AnEntity.FromSqlRaw("Select * from users ORDER BY id").OrderBy(x => x.Title);
```

`ORDER BY id` is ignored, items are sorted by the expression. If no orderby linq expression is used, the framework adds `ORDER BY entity.id`. Otherwise I could have done followings:

```
string itemsQuery = $"SELECT {query} ORDER BY {orderBy} {order}";
context.AnEntity.FromSqlRaw(itemsQuery).Skip(offset).Take(limit)...
```

It works. Even on a table with 1mil a query takes 2,8sec
Comments? Improvment hints?

Edit:
I ended up with a query which loads the paged data in 2,2sec over a table with 1mil rows. Is it an acceptable result?

Comment: Is the Guid-column the primary key?

Comment: Did you look at DynamicLinq or even making your own expression tree for the orderbys? example - https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/256123/52662.   Also you state its an endpoint if it's a webapi project what about just adding OData support for the pagenation?  OData has some flexibility to  intercept the iqueryable.

Comment: yes, the `id (uuid)` column is the primary key.

Comment: @CharlesNRice Didn't know about `DynamicLinq`, will take a look. I am not fan of `OData` but I will give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

- [`PaginationOptions`] Rename `Des` to `OrderByDescending` and remove `OrderBy`, this would be more manageable as you already have a default `order by` in your query.
- I can't see a check for the fields ? if not, try to ensure that every field name exists on your table before building the query.
- Use `Dapper` to count and select queries, as they're faster in dapper than `EF`.
- Since this is a Web API, a `Tuple` would be an overkill for your controller, you might consider returning `IEnumerable` or `IDictionary<int, IList<T>>` or any simpler type, just try to simplify the results to the consumer.
- you can use `FETCH clause` instead of LINQ's `Take` and `Skip`, which would make it faster and also would decrease the allocated memory. referrer to this [page](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-fetch/) to read more about it.
  *(FYI : PostgreSQL, SQL Server, Oracle, and MySQL supports `FETCH clause` with some caveats).*
- `guids` is already a `HashSet<Guid>` so checking the guid in the loop is unnecessary, as the `guids.Add(guid)` would ignore the value if it's already in the collection.

Comment: For the `Count` and `Select` I am using Npgsql, no EF nor Dapper. This `Search` method is not in the controller, it is in an abstract class, called by the controller where i manage the returned items. `Take` and `Skip` are not used on a IO operation since the Guids are already in memory, so it makes no difference, right? Thanks for the rest!

Comment: @Emaborsa if you are using `Npgsql` you should state that, and edit your post to clearify this, as the first line of your post states that you're using `Dapper` and `EF`. for the method, I know it's not the controller. what I meant is the service should always returns simple types, as you don't want to add more data processing inside your controller.

Comment: not sure how things work on your application, but if you just storing guids to re-query the DB with the full data, unless if it's a requirement, you might loose some performance for that. though using `Fetch clause` would give you what you need with faster results.

Comment: About the method: But I need to return the pagend data AND the total items count. About of performance: I agree that is non sense to retrieve all the data and then filter it for the paging, but since the performance is not too bad, I though it was a good solution anyway. I will review the query,.

Answer (score -1):

Just a quick shot at

```
IDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
ISet<Guid> guids = new HashSet<Guid>(paginationOptions.ItemsPerPage);
while (reader.Read())
{
    Guid guid = reader.GetGuid(0);
    if (!guids.Contains(guid))
    {
        guids.Add(guid);
    }
}
ISet<Guid> filteredGuids = guids.Skip(offset).Take(paginationOptions.ItemsPerPage).ToHashSet();
```

Because the Guid-column is your primary-key-column, you should just use a `List<Guid>`. You won't need to check if `reader.GetGuid(0)` exists because that just can't happen.

I wouldn't create the former `HashSet<Guid>` by using the capacity of `paginationOptions.ItemsPerPage` but would use a fixed number which should be in the lower range but not too low. Because if you use this overloaded constructor, then you should use it in a way that it scales good. Having a low number for capacity, you may reach the point fast that there aren't any slots left meaning the `HashSet` needs to be resized. If the number for capacity is too high it may take more time at initialization because its createing two array with the length of the passed capacity.

Take a look at the [reference-source for `HashSet<T>`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.core/system/Collections/Generic/HashSet.cs,831ca3e6d9c0d78b)

This applies for a `List<T>` as well.

To come to an end I would change the code a bove to

```
IDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
List<Guid> guids = new List<Guid>(2000);
while (reader.Read())
{
    guids.Add(reader.GetGuid(0));
}
ISet<Guid> filteredGuids = guids.Skip(offset).Take(paginationOptions.ItemsPerPage).ToHashSet();
```

but would extract the `2000` to a meaningful named constant.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but If the query has a join with, the result could include two rows with the same id and different joined values which are neede for filtering. That's why I used a ISet. I could use a IList, but in this case I`d need the check `if contains...`.

Comment: I've just tried to change from `ISet<Guid> guids = new HashSet<Guid>(paginationOptions.ItemsPerPage);` to `List<Guid> guids = new List<Guid>(2000);`. For the same query the first takes 500ms, the latter 12sec.